# Is it possible to use a parent entity's property in the NSPredicate for a NSFetchRequest?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity A like the following:

```
@interface A : NSManagedObject
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringProperty;
```

that has a subentity B like this:

```
@interface B : A
{
}
```

I would like to perform a fetch on B using a property stored in A. Something like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate mainManagedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B"     inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stringProperty = %@", someString];
[request setPredicate:pred];
```

Is this possible? I am currently getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath stringProperty not found in entity <NSSQLEntity B id=26>'
```

Comment: Can you describe your entity hierarchy a bit more and show the actual predicate you're using?

Comment: I have updated my question with more specific code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried a similar example in the latest SDK (4.3) and it now works. I can now use the parent entities' properties in a predicate for a subentity.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to call `superentity`? ie

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"superentity.stringProperty = %@", someString];
```

Or you could fetch entity A and `setIncludesSubentitles:YES` for your fetch request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where nobody responded for so long, I have moved on and, as I recall, I just changed my hierarchy. When I get some time I will try out your solution and accept your answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried to use superentity.stringProperty and got the following error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath superentity.stringProperty not found in entity <NSSQLEntity B id=13>

Comment: Also, setIncludesSubentities:YES is not an option because I only want B entities in the result.